# the simple present tense or the present continuous tense

Tags: grammar, tense

Write the verbs in the brackets in a suitable form of simple present or present continuous to the given blanks

> It (rain) _______, why don't you take your umbrella?
>   Who _______ you (wait) _______ for?

My answer is "rains" for the first sentence. For the second one it is "do-wait"
But the answer key says: "is raining, are-waiting"
There are not any time expressions in these sentences. Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *present continuous*, and not the *simple present*, is called for in both of these sentences.

We use the *present continuous* (or *present progressive*) to talk about events or conditions that are in *progress* or unfinished at the time of speaking. We use the *simple present* to talk about events or conditions that take place in general.

When we say "It rains", we say only that rain falls, without any reference to the time of the event. When we say "It is raining", we say that the rain falls *as we speak*.

Thus, the *present continuous* is correct in your first sentence:

> It **is raining**, why don't you take your umbrella?

It is sensible to take the umbrella if the rain is *in progress* at the time of speaking. If the undeniable fact that *"it rains"* were a plausible reason to carry an umbrella, everyone would carry an umbrella every moment of every day!

In your second sentence, the same principle applies. When we say "You wait", we say only that the subject waits, without any reference to time. When we say "You are waiting" (or, with *subject–auxiliary inversion* in the interrogative form, "Are you waiting"), we say that the person waits at the moment when we speak.

Thus, the *present continuous* is also correct in your second sentence:

> Who **are** you **waiting** for?